# How do I identify the id of the "<app>" component or selector app-administration-treatment-plan-history

Tags: angular

In the patient-roster-search.component.html when I click on the link I called the method `onViewPatientTreatmentHistory(row)`.

In the patient-roster-search-component.ts file how do I find the `AdministrationTreatmentPlanHistoryComponent` that is created from 
`<app-administration-treatment-plan-history></app-administration-treatment-plan-history>`?
Or how do I find the selector app-administration-treatment-plan-history in administration-treatment-plan-history.component.ts?

---

patient-roster-component.html:

```
<div style="display:block" id="patientRosterSearch"><app-patient-roster-search></app-patient-roster-search></div>

<div style="display:none" id="administrationTreatmentPlanHistory"><app-administration-treatment-plan-history></app-administration-treatment-plan-history></div>
```

patient-roster-search.component.html:

```
<td class="tblRow actionRow small">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="{‌{rowData.mrn}}" (click)="onViewPatientTreatmentPlanHistory(rowData)">View</button>
</td>
```

patient-roster-search-component.ts:

```
onViewPatientTreatmentPlanHistory(item) {
 this.patient = new  AdministrationTreatmentPlanHistoryComponent();
 this.patient.onViewPatientTreatmentPlanHistory(item);
 return this.patient;
}
```

administration-treatment-plan-history.component.ts:

``````````````
export class AdministrationTreatmentPlanHistoryComponent implements OnInit {

@Component({
  selector: 'app-administration-treatment-plan-history',
  templateUrl: './administration-treatment-plan-history.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./administration-treatment-plan-history.component.css']
})

ngOnInit() {
  this.planName = "John Plan";
}

onViewPatientTreatmentPlanHistory(item) {
  document.getElementById("administrationTreatmentPlanHistory").style.display="block";
  document.getElementById("patientRosterSearch").style.display="none";
  this.planName= item.firstName;
}
`````````````
``````````````

Comment: What is `administration-treatment-plan-history.component` and can you update your question with it's template code. What is it's parent component and what is the relationship between `patient-roster-search-component` and `administration-treatment-plan-history.component`

Comment: The patient-roster-search-component.html contains the "administration-treatment-plan-history.component" through the following html code: <div style="display:none" id="administrationTreatmentPlanHistory"><app-administration-treatment-plan-history></app-administration-treatment-plan-history></div>. In the patient-roster-search-component.html it contains the following html in the search result:<td class="tblRow actionRow small">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="{‌{rowData.mrn}}" (click)="onViewPatientTreatmentPlanHistory(rowData)">View</button>

</td>

Comment: When the person click on this link it trigger the method onViewPatientTreatmentPlanHistory(rowData) in the patient-roster-search-component.ts. 

In the patient-roster-search-component.ts it calls the following code:  onViewPatientTreatmentPlanHistory(item) {

   this.patient = new  AdministrationTreatmentPlanHistoryComponent();

   this.patient.onViewPatientTreatmentPlanHistory(item);

   return this.patient;

  }

Comment: The problem is that it should not do this: new AdministrationTreatmentPlanHistoryComponent(). Instead I should find the existing AdministrationTreatmentPlanHistoryComponent that was created when I used the "div style="display:none" id="administrationTreatmentPlanHistory"><app-administration-treatment-plan-history></app-administration-treatment-plan-history></div>"

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the "Angular" way to accomplish this, you're missing out on some of the best features of the framework. Generally, if you need to show/hide elements based on a value, you should be using the `*ngIf` binding. Additionally, you should pass data between components using `@Input` and `@Output` annotations.

I don't know the proper types, but you could accomplish it like this:

patient-roster-component.ts:

```
public selectedPatientPlanHistory;
```

patient-roster-component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="!selectedPatientPlanHistory"><app-patient-roster-search (onPatientPlanHistorySelect)="selectedPatientPlanHistory = $event"></app-patient-roster-search></div>

<div *ngIf="selectedPatientPlanHistory"><app-administration-treatment-plan-history></app-administration-treatment-plan-history [selectedPatientPlanHistory]="selectedPatientPlanHistory"></div>
```

patient-roster-search.component.html:

```
<td class="tblRow actionRow small">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="{‌{rowData.mrn}}" (click)="onViewPatientTreatmentPlanHistory(rowData)">View</button>
</td>
```

patient-roster-search-component.ts:

```
@Output()
public onPatientPlanHistorySelect = new EventEmitter();

onViewPatientTreatmentPlanHistory(item) {
  this.onPatientPlanHistorySelect.emit(item);
}
```

administration-treatment-plan-history.component.ts:

```
export class AdministrationTreatmentPlanHistoryComponent implements OnInit {

@Component({
  selector: 'app-administration-treatment-plan-history',
  templateUrl: './administration-treatment-plan-history.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./administration-treatment-plan-history.component.css']
})

@Input()
public selectedPatientPlanHistory;
```

administration-treatment-plan-history.component.ts:

```
<div *ngIf="selectedPatientPlanHistory">{{selectedPatientPlanHistory.firstName}}</div>
```

---

Now your two components are not dependent on each other (they are not tightly coupled) and modifying or debugging them can be accomplished in smaller chunks.

I recommend [this documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) for more information about this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Vlad. Greatly appreciated it!! I am new to Angular so  I will have to spend some considerable time trying to understand your answer and the link you provide. Thank you!!!

Comment: @jadeite1000 Based on your use of `document.getElementById`, I'm guessing you're more familiar with vanilla JS or jQuery. Either way, when I was starting out with Angular, I found the "Tour of Heros" tutorial by Angular to be very helpful. If you're looking for more information, I highly recommend that resource.

Comment: @jadeite1000 - Consider accepting the answer (with the green check mark) if it solved your problem. Accepting and upvoting answers are the best ways to say "Thank you" on StackOverflow.

Comment: @jadeite1000 To respond to your other comment about `[]` vs `()`: Yes, that is basically correct. `[A]=X` is an Input binding meaning "set the child component's variable A to X". and `(A)="X` is an Output binding meaning "if the child component says A happened, do X"